# How to implement the behavior of image tapping like what the Notes app does in iOS 9.x?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am practicing a notes app, in which I use `NSAttributedString` to store the words and photo inputted in this app.
    Now I am trying to implement the image tapping behavior like what the Notes app does in iOS 9.x, in which if the added photo is tapped, the screen turns to another mode, like the screenshots below.

[screenshots of the Notes App in iOS 9.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxvgc.png)

After searching Google and Stackoverflow, I found the `textView:shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:inRange:` method of `NSAttributedString` may be used to catch the tapping image behavior.  However, this results in the words and photo not editable because it is necessary to make `self.myTextField.editable = NO` in order to enable the method above.  Maybe it is possible to make a button to switch between`self.myTextField.editable = NO` and `self.myTextField.editable = YES`, but I'm still hope to implement what the notes app (in which there is no such a switch button) does in iOS 9.x.

Comment: you can simply add tap gesture recogniser to the imageView or uiview and then you can give the code to move to other view.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you, I'll try this.

Comment: this might be of use to you https://github.com/MailOnline/ImageViewer

Comment: thank you @Mr.T and @Hayden.  It seems that a gesture recognizer is available for UIView only.  I use `NSAttributedString` to store images and texts, and use `myTextview.attributedtext` to show them in my textview.  However, I wish to apply a gesture recognizer to the image only but not to the texts.  Is it possible?  Or is there any way to detect a tap behavior on the images but not on the texts when they are in the same textview?